# add query string in Microsoft oauth 2.0 redirect url for token acquisition

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently developing an App using Microsoft LIVE 2.0 API

Currently, I’m using these URLs as my authentication endpoints:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

However, when I sent the request to the token endpoint with the redirect URL as

`https://blabla.com/accept_token.php?api_ver=wave5&csrf=AY7F6O4hF0n8yW3i2O_y6N-ky7zzfULiYV_fttLK1S3JgaeQz2GTk9FOeIGBBH5CvkfkEYCyPOCQCujcrij4KDy2wAMZyXqx24jvwZRtzOv0s9ADGYl1iFtvYtkmgeFmZEY&appdata=%7B%22use_case%22%3A1%2C%22type%22%3A1%2C%22flow%22%3A2%2C%22domain_id%22%3A12%2C%22tracked_params%22%3A%22%5B%5D%22%7D`

I got errors saying the reply address does not match the reply addresses configured for the application

For the application, I set the reply address to be `https://blabla.com/accept_token.php`.

Is it possible that I add some parameters to the url and still make it match?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the reply url you send must match exactly the reply url registered on the application, including any query strings.

If there is variable state informaiton you need passed throughout the authentication process, you should use the `state` variable.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code

> state
>
> > A value included in the request that will also be returned in the token response. It can be a string of any content that you wish. A randomly generated unique value is typically used for preventing cross-site request forgery attacks. The state is also used to encode information about the user's state in the app before the authentication request occurred, such as the page or view they were on.

Comment: This is correct. You should encode any additional data and provide it in the `state` parameter. This will be returned back to your server as a `state` query parameter appended to the Redirect URI you provided.

Comment: This is just awful. I am trying to use the same code to connect to multiple Oauth2.0 providers. My Redirect URI contains a parameter to identify the Oauth2.0 provider, which the user chose before. And the "state" query parameter is prohibited in case of Google Oauth2.0

Comment: @IvanKuckir I'm stuck with something similar, do you have any workaround for scenario you gave ?